# Target this Parent's Children only in Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I've multiple Parents with the same class `(.wowParent)` on the same page. With my current code it doesn't target exclusively the current Parent's Children but also those of the other `(.wowParent)`... I need it to add delay only on Child of current Parent in Vanilla JavaScript but I can't figure out how to do it

Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Apache349089/om4cyf12/) "better" explaining the problem

```
<div class="wowParent">
    <div class="wow"></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div class="wow"></div>
    <div class="wow"></div>
    <div class="wow"></div>
</div>
```

Here's my current code:

```
// delay the next element by 100ms
var delay = 0;
const array = document.querySelectorAll(".wowParent .wow");
for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    delay = delay + 100; // delay by 100ms
    index += 0;
    // reset loop every 4
    if(index % 4 == 0) { delay = 0; }
    array[index].style.setProperty('--delay', delay + "ms");
}
```

Comment: *Child of current Parent* ... each `.wow` is a child of a single `.wowParent` - so, what is a "current" Parent? You only show a single `wowParent` in your example, so all the `.wow` shown share one (current) parent

Comment: Not understanding your "delay" language. Something new?

Comment: Perhaps the code needs to iterate all the `.wowParent` and within this loop, it can iterate through the `.wow` within the `.wowParent` ... so, a nested loop

Comment: @GetSet ... the delay would be 0, 100, 200, 300, 0, 100, 200, 300 etc - though it is a funky way of doing it ... the `index += 0` is basically a no-op, and  in reality `delay = (index % 4) * 100` - but why do in one line what can be done in 3 :p

Comment: @JaromandaX I've created a Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Apache349089/om4cyf12

Comment: @Apache349089 - so? does my answer fix your problem or not? It seems it would (I have read that fiddle and used my code and it seems to do what you want0

Comment: @GetSet it's a CSS var

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this nested loop does what you need

```
document.querySelectorAll(".wowParent").forEach(parent => {
  parent.querySelectorAll(".wow").forEach((child, index) => {
    const delay = (index % 4) * 1000;
    child.style.setProperty('--delay', delay + "ms");
  });
});
```

Comment: This change definitely needs to be made so that the style changes are made to the `.wow` divs, rather than the `.wowParent` divs, but I'm guessing from OP's wording that they want a way to limit the results of `document.querySelectorAll(".wowParent")` to return only the "current" `.wowParent` div...whatever that means

Comment: @awarrier99 - I figured the `delay` "cycle" starts at 0 with every parent? Really, I just posted an answer because comments were not getting anywhere :p

Comment: Hahaha yup honestly your guess is as good as mine. @Apache349089 can you elaborate on what the "current" parent is? Is it perhaps an element which you click on or hover over to give it the "current" state you were referring to?

Comment: Here's a Fiddle of what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/Apache349089/om4cyf12/

Comment: Oh, so does this help @Apache349089? there was a typo in my code, so it should work now

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, now it's working. Previously it gave an error. Thank you a lot that's what I was trying to do. I've a lot to learn about Vanilla Js :(

Comment: As i said, I had a typo (foEach instead of forEach)